# Is tf.gradients thread-safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow

I have several calls to `tf.gradients` that each take some time, thus I would like to concurrently call `tf.gradients`. However, I receive one of several errors when I try to do so in my graph. I suspect it is not thread-safe, but have not been able to reproduce the error with a MWE. I tried using both `pathos.pools.ThreadPool` and `pathos.pools.ProcessPool` in both my MWE and real code -
 only my real code fails. Here is the MWE that I tried:

```
from pathos.pools import ThreadPool, ProcessPool
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

Xs = [tf.cast(np.random.random((10,10)), dtype=tf.float64) for i in range(3)]
Ys = [Xs[0]*Xs[1]*Xs[2], Xs[0]/Xs[1]*Xs[2], Xs[0]/Xs[1]/Xs[2]]

def compute_grad(YX):
    return tf.gradients(YX[0], YX[1])

tp = ThreadPool(3)
res = tp.map(compute_grad, zip(Ys, Xs))
print(res)
```

Here's a partial traceback I encountered when trying my real code. This is the `ThreadPool` version.

```
File "pathos/threading.py", line 134, in map
    return _pool.map(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
  File "multiprocess/pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "multiprocess/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
  File "multiprocess/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "multiprocess/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "pathos/helpers/mp_helper.py", line 15, in <lambda>
    func = lambda args: f(*args)
  File "my_code.py", line 939, in gradients_with_index
    return (tf.gradients(Y, variables), b_idx)
  File "tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 448, in gradients
    colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File "tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 188, in _PendingCount
    between_op_list, between_ops, colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File "tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1288, in MaybeCreateControlFlowState
    loop_state.AddWhileContext(op, between_op_list, between_ops)
  File "tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1103, in AddWhileContext
    grad_state = GradLoopState(forward_ctxt, outer_grad_state)
  File "tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 737, in __init__
    cnt, outer_grad_state)
  File "tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2282, in AddBackPropLoopCounter
    merge_count = merge([enter_count, enter_count])[0]
  File "tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 404, in merge
    return gen_control_flow_ops._merge(inputs, name)
  File "tensorflow/python/ops/gen_control_flow_ops.py", line 150, in _merge
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Merge", inputs=inputs, name=name)
  File "tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1273, in __init__
    self._control_flow_context.AddOp(self)
  File "tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2147, in AddOp
    self._AddOpInternal(op)
  File "tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2177, in _AddOpInternal
    self._MaybeAddControlDependency(op)
  File "tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2204, in _MaybeAddControlDependency
    op._add_control_input(self.GetControlPivot().op)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'op'
```

Here is another traceback. Note the error is different

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 869, in AddForwardAccumulator
    enter_acc = self.forward_context.AddValue(acc)
  File "tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2115, in AddValue
    self._outer_context.AddInnerOp(enter.op)
  File "tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3355, in __exit__
    self._graph._pop_control_dependencies_controller(self)
  File "tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3375, in _pop_control_dependencies_controller
    assert self._control_dependencies_stack[-1] is controller
AssertionError
```

The `ProcessPool` version encountered the error:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'tensorflow.python.util.tf_should_use._add_should_use_warning.<locals>.TFShouldUseWarningWrapper'>: it's not found as tensorflow.python.util.tf_should_use._add_should_use_warning.<locals>.TFShouldUseWarningWrapper
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tf.gradients()` function is **not thread-safe**. It makes a sequence of complicated and non-atomic modifications to your graph, and these are not protected by locks. In particular, it seems that using `tf.gradients()` on a graph that contains control flow operations (such as `tf.while_loop()`) is more likely to run into problems if you run it concurrently.

Note that it is unlikely that issuing parallel calls to `tf.gradients()` would speed it up—even if it were implemented in a thread-safe manner. The function performs no I/O and does not call any native methods that release Python's [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), so the execution would most likely be serialized. Implementing `multiprocessing`-based parallelism would require additional system calls for accessing the shared graph (and acquiring/releasing locks), so it is unlikely that this would be faster.